# If I use weight_col with flow_from_dataframe and a custom loss function do I have to take it into account in the loss function or is it automatic?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, loss-function

In my problem I have to account for an imbalance between the samples and I also made a custom loss function and so I was wondering if I should take those weights into account in the loss function or was it automatic?

I use `flow_from_dataframe` to pass the data with the parameter `weight_col`.

So I have to do something like this?

```
def my_loss(y_true,y_pred):
    mae_func = tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError()
    mae = mae_func(y_true,y_pred)
    return mae
```

Or like this?

```
def my_loss(y_true,y_pred,weight):
    mae_func = tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError()
    # Do some operations with weights
    mae = mae_func(y_true,y_pred)
    return mae
```

Comment: Need some more details on your query. Could you please share some more details with reproducible code to understand the issue better?